# How to deal with error in converting spreadsheet to excel file and saving it to my google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, download

I am trying to convert my spreadsheet file to an excel file and want to
    save the excel file to my google drive with google apps script. When I 
    run this script, I always receive the error message below.

> "The feature you are attempting to use has been disabled by your domain 
>       administrator at the 21st line."

Could you give me how to deal with this error?
    There is my spreadsheet to be converted on my google drive and I want to 
    save the converted excel file to my google drive. Here is my code for
    google apps script. There are some variables in this code below.
    They are myFunction, id, SpreadsheetID, excel_file, ss2xlsx, new_file,
    url, options, res and ss.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var id = "e.g. SpreadsheetID";
  var excel_file = ss2xlsx(id);
  if (excel_file !== undefined) {
    Logger.log("Name:" + excel_file.getName());
  }
}

//To convert spreadsheet to excel and save the file to my google drive
function ss2xlsx(spreadsheet_id) {
  var new_file;
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet_id +
    "/export?format=xlsx";
  var options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (res.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet_id);
    new_file = DriveApp.createFile(res.getBlob()).setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
  }
  return new_file;
}
```

Comment: Contact your admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The administrator of your G Suite domain has disabled the permission to allow users to access Google Drive with the Drive API. The admin can re-enable this option by going to admin.google.com -> Apps -> G Suite -> Settings for Drive and Docs -> Features and Applications.